# How to check whether jenkins is installed in windows or not?

Tags: windows, jenkins, installation

I'm very new to it , But while learning postman i got it as prerequisite ,
can anyone please tell me how i can check jenkins is installed or not in windows.

Answer (score 0):

In your browser try to access `http://localhost:8080` and when you go there and see anything related to "Jenkins", then Jenkins is installed and you might require unlocking. Read here: https://www.guru99.com/download-install-jenkins.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check via this link https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/. I'm sure there is a part on checking whether Jenkins is installed or not.